# Error while in deploying project into jBoss

Tags: java, jboss, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, ear

I am using EJB3.0 and jBoss 5.0.1

My project is successfully deployed but when I run Jboss server I got the following error

DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=cccrmapp.ear,jar=cccrmapp.jar,name=CustomerFacade,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "" (should be in state "Described", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:cccrmapp/CustomerSessionBean/local-com.cc.crm.bl.master.customer.session.CustomerSessionBeanLocal' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=cccrmapp.ear,jar=cccrmapp.jar,name=CustomerSessionBean,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "" (should be in state "Described", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'Class:com.cc.crm.bl.master.customer.session.CustomerSessionBean' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=cccrmapp.ear,jar=cccrmapp.jar,name=InvoiceFacade,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "" (should be in state "Described", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:cccrmapp/CustomerSessionBean/local-com.cc.crm.bl.master.customer.session.CustomerSessionBeanLocal' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=cccrmapp.ear,jar=cccrmapp.jar,name=PromotionalMailFacade,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "" (should be in state "Described", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:cccrmapp/CustomerSessionBean/local-com.cc.crm.bl.master.customer.session.CustomerSessionBeanLocal' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=cccrmapp.ear,jar=cccrmapp.jar,name=PromotionalSMSFacade,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "" (should be in state "Described", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:cccrmapp/CustomerSessionBean/local-com.cc.crm.bl.master.customer.session.CustomerSessionBeanLocal' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=cccrmapp.ear,jar=cccrmapp.jar,name=VoucherFacade,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "" (should be in state "Described", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:cccrmapp/CustomerSessionBean/local-com.cc.crm.bl.master.customer.session.CustomerSessionBeanLocal' **")

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:cccrmapp/CustomerSessionBean/local-com.cc.crm.bl.master.customer.session.CustomerSessionBeanLocal' **
  Deployment "" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:cccrmapp/CustomerSessionBean/local-com.cc.crm.bl.master.customer.session.CustomerSessionBeanLocal' **
  Deployment "" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:cccrmapp/CustomerSessionBean/local-com.cc.crm.bl.master.customer.session.CustomerSessionBeanLocal' **
  Deployment "" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:cccrmapp/CustomerSessionBean/local-com.cc.crm.bl.master.customer.session.CustomerSessionBeanLocal' **
  Deployment "" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jndi:cccrmapp/CustomerSessionBean/local-com.cc.crm.bl.master.customer.session.CustomerSessionBeanLocal' **
  Deployment "" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'Class:com.cc.crm.bl.master.customer.session.CustomerSessionBean' **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like something is expecting to find a local interface for `CustomerSessionBean`. Who is supposed to provide it? If this EJB belongs to your EAR, are you sure deployment went well?